# Escaping a single quote in Oracle regex query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

This is really starting to hurt!

I'm attempting to write a query in Oracle developer using a regex condition

My objective is to find all last names that contain charachters not commonly contained in names (non-alpha, spaces, hyphens and single quotes)

i.e.
I need to find

```
J00ls
McDonald "Macca"
Smithy (Smith)
```

and NOT find

```
Smith
Mckenzie-Smith
El Hassan
O'Dowd
```

My present query is

```
select * from dm_name 
WHERE regexp_like(last_name, '([^A-Za-z -])')
and batch_id = 'ATEST';
```

which excludes everything expected except the single quote. When it comes to putting the single quote character, the Oracvel SQL Develoepr parser takes it as a literal.

I've tried:

```
\' -- but got a "missing right parenthesis" error
||chr(39)|| -- but the search returned nothing
'' -- negated the previous character in the matching group e.g. '([^A-Za-z -''])' made names with '-' return.
```

I'd appreciate anything you could offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works:

```
select * 
  from dm_name 
  WHERE regexp_like(last_name, '([^A-Za-z ''-])');
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd9e9/4).

Whether SQL Developer will like it or not is something I cannot attest to as I don't have that product installed.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 6):

Just double the single quote to escape your quote.

So

```
select *
  from dm_name
 where regexp_like(last_name, '[^A-Za-z ''-]')
   and batch_id = 'ATEST'
```

See also this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca59f/3).  Note, I tried a similar query in SQL developer and that worked as well as the fiddle.

Note also, for this to work the `-` character has to be the last character in the group as otherwise it tries to find the group `SPACE` to `'` rather than the character `-`.